# docker swarm how to get all container ip using dns?

Tags: dns, docker-swarm, swarm

I create two service, `service-a`(3 replies) and `service-b`(5 replies).
They are in `micro` overlay network.

I want to get all container ip from dns.

```
# docker run --rm --network micro alpine nslookup service-a
```

But only get one ip. Is there has anyway to get all IPs address of some service using dns?

Comment: Were you able to figure out how to list the services from within a container?

Answer (score 0):

Use `tasks.<service-name>` to get all containers belonging to particular service.

Answer (score -1):

You can use `docker inspect` to get the virtual IP of a service:

```
NETWORK_ID=$(docker network ls -q --no-trunc --filter name=micro) && docker service inspect service-a -f "{{range \$i, \$value := .Endpoint.VirtualIPs}} {{if eq \$value.NetworkID \"$NETWORK_ID\" }}{{$value.Addr}}{{end}}{{end}}"
```

This one line command finds the network ID then use it in a `docker inspect` to get only the services virtual IPs in this network, using the -f (format) parameter